# How do I stop all unit test if the first one fails?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mstest

I am having like 100+ unit tests for a project, but if a special condition fails in the first test, I want the other tests to **stop**, or to now even start executing. How do I do that?

Comment: Side note if you want this because your tests are depending on each other rethink that. The different testing framework have different behaviors but i don't know of any that provides this. You may set a flag on error and then check for that flag in your test setup and then shortcut the tests in case.

Comment: Some good discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274655/how-to-make-one-test-depend-on-the-results-of-another-test) on why you shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: The main problem is that the tests authenticate with a company user, but if it has its password changed, then the tests would fail, and the user is going to be locked, because of the failed login attempts. I know its not the best solution, but this is know what I asked for.

Comment: This means your tests aren't unit tests and are already super brittle since they rely on an external source. You should really consider using things like mocks and such.

Comment: I am using mocks. Im having connection mocks, which are returning the corresponding user's username, password etc etc. My services use these mocks in the tests.

Comment: So how can a password change affect your tests?

Comment: As others have mentioned, this setup is likely flawed in and of itself, but if there's no alternative you could move the common initialization to a `[ClassInitialize]` or even `[AssemblyInitialize]` method. If that method throws, all tests in the respective context will fail. Make sure to clearly separate integration tests like these (because that's what they are if they have external dependencies) from unit tests -- automated tests are not all created equal, and it's important to know which tests can always run after every build, and which cannot or should not.